# Composing network request with RX and Kotlin

Tags: android, system.reactive, retrofit, rx-java, kotlin

I am working on an Android application that uses kotlin with RXJava and Retrofit for network calls. On startup, the application will do several network calls to a REST-like backend. The procedure look very much like the one used by Netflix in their examples. However when trying to rewrite it to work with Kotlin I am struggling. I have trouble understanding how returns work in Kotlin closures. Would very much appreciate some help here!

Netflix example:

```
    return getUser(userId).flatMap(user -> {
        Observable<Map<String, Object>> catalog =    getPersonalizedCatalog(user)
            .flatMap(catalogList -> catalogList.videos().<Map<String, Object>> flatMap(
                    video -> {
                        Observable<Bookmark> bookmark = getBookmark(video);
                        Observable<Rating> rating = getRatings(video);
                        Observable<VideoMetadata> metadata = getVideoMetadata(video);
                        return Observable.zip(bookmark, rating, metadata, (b, r, m) -> combineVideoData(video, b, r, m));
                    }));

    Observable<Map<String, Object>> social = getSocial(user).map(s -> {
        return s.getDataAsMap();
    });

    return Observable.merge(catalog, social);
}).flatMap(data -> {
    String json = SimpleJson.mapToJson(data);
    return response.writeStringAndFlush("data: " + json + "\n");
});
```

My solution:

```
restClient.getVideoList("VAR1", "VAR2")
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .flatMap { videos -> Observable.from(videos)}
                .map { video ->
                    var actors: Observable<List<Actor>> = restClient.getActorList(video.id(), "VAR2")
                    var price = restClient.getPrice(video.id(), "VAR2")
                    Observable.zip(actors, price, { (a, p) ->  combineVideoData(video, a, p)})
                }.map{ video -> doSomethingWithVideo(video) }
```

For some reason my implementation returns an observable and not a video object which it i supposed to. There is no doubt something wrong with my understanding of closures in Kotlin, and I have tried to figure it out for days, but still struggling. Would be very grateful for any help!

Comment: As mentioned in the answers (you didn't accept one, did you not find a solution?) you need to terminate the observable with some action.  ideas are below in the answers.  Can you please update which answer helped, or if you found another solutions so others know the results?

Comment: If you started a new project I strongly advice you to use coroutines instead of RX, this is the new and recommended way, since you will use them to make non-blocking code also.

Answer (score 1):

You have created the observable but didn't subscribed to it. You should use `forEach {}` (from RxKotlin) or `subscribe {}` instead of the last `map`. It would look like

```
restClient
    .getVideoList("VAR1", "VAR2")
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .flatMap { videos -> Observable.from(videos)}
    .map { video ->
        var actors: Observable<List<Actor>> = restClient.getActorList(video.id(), "VAR2")
        var price = restClient.getPrice(video.id(), "VAR2")
        Observable.zip(actors, price, { (a, p) ->  combineVideoData(video, a, p)})
    }
    .forEach { video -> doSomethingWithVideo(video) }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you manipulate an observable, you'll get a new observable.

If you want to get your value out of your observable, you'll have to quit it ("exit the monad") by blocking it :

```
val value = yourObs.toBlocking().first()
```